# Summing user input data (integer)

Tags: python, input, integer, sum

I want to do something really simple and add some integer user input (for example 1 2 3 4 5). I have int before my input call but I still keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'
```

My code:

```
data = int(input("Enter the expenses: "))
data_sum = sum(data)
print("Total: ", data_sum)
```

Any help would be great
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You pass `'1 2 3 4 5'` to `int()`, but `'1 2 3 4 5'` is not a valid number, so you get the **ValueError**.
You can try the following code:

```
data = [int(i) for i in input("Enter the expenses:").split()]
data_sum = sum(data)
print("Total: ", data_sum)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ren, this technique was exactly what I was after and worked perfectly :-) Thank you for helping! (+1 rep but still building my reputation before my vote for your answer can be displayed publicly)